# How to get the 'inProgress' items from Jenkins queue

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins

I am working on a plugin and I need to know if a job is pending or is in progress, debuging I see that there is a **'inProgress'** list that I can't seem to access from java. How can I access it? 
[image: inProgress list I don't know how to access]

The only method I found that may be related is **jenkins.getQueue().isPending();** but this doesn't return the items on this list.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research I found that this is a behavior not supported.
What I ended up doing as a work around is a loop on the Executors (using computer->getExecutors) and asked them (using getCurrentExecutable->getParent) what task was their parent task.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information if job in queue is pending by executing this script:

```
Jenkins.instance.queue.items.each {
    println it.isPending()
}
```

It's written in Groovy and I executed from Jenkins script console. Basically `getQueue()` returns a list on which you should iterate.

Comment: thanks but the pending list is empty (you can see this in the pic I posted, just a few places up from the one selected), after some debugging I saw that the job gets there and then leaves it as soon as the build is started, and this is the info I want when the job gets/stays in this 'currently building' state